# Eclipse autoformat initialization of variables

Tags: java, eclipse, format, autoformatting

normally Eclipse does autoformatting of initializations like this:

```
createLog = false;
experimentDuration = 1;
rampUpInterval = 1.0;
rampUpNumUsersPerInterval = 1;
coolDownInterval = 1;
coolDownNumUsersPerInterval = 1;
numUsers = 1;
thinkTimeMinimum = 1000;
thinkTimeMaximum = 1000;
```

I would like to have a autoformat rule to format the initializations like this:

```
createLog                   = false;
experimentDuration          = 1;
rampUpInterval              = 1.0;
rampUpNumUsersPerInterval   = 1;
coolDownInterval            = 1;
coolDownNumUsersPerInterval = 1;
numUsers                    = 1;
thinkTimeMinimum            = 1000;
thinkTimeMaximum            = 1000;
```

Does someone knows where I can adjust this?

**€dit:** I would like to have this alignment in the contructor.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto `Windows->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter` in that Edit the active profile and check the `Align fields in column` option

[image]

Comment: Too bad, that is only for fields. I would like to have this alignment in my constructor. But thanks anyway.